# Need to insert my python fucntion value into an exisiting table in databricks

Tags: python, sql, database, scala, pyspark

I have a function that returns the sla value (for when a request comes in ) only considering business hours,

```
def processDifference(enter_time, exit_time,  key):
     ...logic is here ...
    return sla_time
```

this works fine

now I have a table in databricks that has case_id ,enter_time , exit_time, key, so I want to append the new column(sla_time) in the already existing table and be able to pass values from my python function

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? What is wrong with your existing code?  Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask], [mre] and the other links found on those pages.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, your DataFrame (df) might be

```
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
|case_id|enter_time         |exit_time          |key  |
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
|1      |2023-04-07 10:00:00|2023-04-07 11:00:00|a_key|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
```

Importing necessary package

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
```

In order to use your `Python function` in Spark, we need to register it as an `UDF` and use it with DataFrame columns.

```
def processDifference(enter_time, exit_time, key):
    return "some_sla_time"

processDifferenceUdf = udf(processDifference) # <-- Registering function as UDF

df \
.withColumn("sla_time", processDifferenceUdf("enter_time","exit_time","key")) \
.show(truncate=False)
```

Output

```
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+-------------+
|case_id|enter_time         |exit_time          |key  |sla_time     |
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+-------------+
|1      |2023-04-07 10:00:00|2023-04-07 11:00:00|a_key|some_sla_time|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+-------------+
```